# Allow ONLY Letters in Keyboard - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to create a `TextField` in Jetpack Compose for users to enter their first and last name.

Is there a way to allow ONLY letters and whitespaces (`[a-zA-Z\s]`) as input? I've tried every single option available, including `KeyboardType.Text`, `KeyboardType.Ascii`, `KeyboardType.Uri`, but they all show numbers!

Am I missing something obvious? Honestly, I'm kind of shocked that Google doesn't offer this option out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```kotlin
val pattern = remember { Regex("[a-zA-z\\s]*") }
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.matches(pattern)) {
            text = it
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right direction, but ideally, I would like to prevent showing non-letters in the first place. I guess that's not possible as of now...

Answer (score 2):

In Android it's not possible to show a keyboard containing only letters (and it's not related to compose). Keyboard apps don't support it either.

There are other kinds of keyboards (like number-only keyboard), but the view of the keyboard is still controlled by the keyboard app.

It's best to filter the given input based on the needed criteria. For example:

```kotlin
onValueChange = {
    text = it.letters()
}

private fun String.letters() = filter { it.isLetter() }
```